# Подключение нестандартных шрифтов

Tags: html, css

Шрифт, которого нет в https://fonts.google.com/. Поэтому благодаря этому сайту http://www.web-font-generator.com/ скачала нужный мне шрифт, поместила в папку font. и давай подключать в css

```
`@font-face {
  font-family: 'BloggerSans-Medium';
  src: url('../font/BloggerSans-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}`
```

Изменила путь к самому файлу, и конечно же написала `font-family:'BloggerSans-Medium'`
Но все равно не получается. ребята, в чем ошибка, кто с таким сталкивался??

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами `font-family: 'BloggerSans-Medium';
 ` и `src: url('../font/BloggerSans-Medium.eot') format('embedded-opentype');`

Comment: @Yernar, нет, все по старому(

Answer (score 0):

Ребят, все получилось. заново все сделала, но теперь при скачивание файла на сайте https://www.web-font-generator.com/, поставила галочку только на --
I'm uploading a font that is legal for web embedding. I checked with the author and/or EULA. файл styles.css оказался теперь совсем другим, потом везде поставила пути к папке и все ок. может кому-то пригодится)